# Out of stack space

Tags: excel, vba

I've been trying to fix this for a long time.
My stacks show:

```
VBAProject.RecebeContratos.ParseHTML3
[<The code isnt Basic>]
VBAProject.Módulo1.TodosContratosOrgao5
[<The code isnt Basic>] '(I don't know the exact translation for this, my excel is in portuguese)
```

Then it loops again

```
Sub TodosContratosOrgao5(MacroLoop As Long, Z As Long)
    Dim URL As String
    Dim ultimo As Long
    Dim ultimoorgao As Long
    Set rng = Range("D2:D589")
    If MacroLoop = 0 Or MacroLoop = 1 Then
        MacroLoop = 3
    End If
    Do While MacroLoop <= 589
        If Plan4.Range("E1") = Plan5.Range("E" & MacroLoop) Then
            URL = Plan5.Range("C" & MacroLoop).Value
            Call ParseHTML3(URL, MacroLoop, Z, "") 'Here it stops with the stack error
        End If
        MacroLoop = MacroLoop + 1
    Loop
End Sub
```

Any thoughts?
I don't know how to stop these loops from stacking up.

Thank you all!

```
Function ParseHTML3(URL As String, MacroLoop As Long, Z As Long, Teste As String)

    Dim htm As Object: Set htm = CreateObject("htmlfile")
    Dim tr As Object
    Dim td As Object
    Dim X As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim URL2 As Long
    Dim htmlColl As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
    Dim htmlElem As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
    Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
    Application.StatusBar = "Recebendo Contratos... Aguarde!"
    Dim shellWins As ShellWindows
    Dim IE As InternetExplorer
    Range("D1").Calculate
    Range("E1").Calculate
    Set shellWins = New ShellWindows

                            'Create IE
    Set IE = New InternetExplorer
    On Error Resume Next
    IE.Visible = True
    On Error GoTo 0
    If Teste = "" Then
        If URL = Plan4.Range("C1").Value Then
            GoTo Termina
        End If
    End If
    IE.Navigate URL
    'Aguarda IE completar o carregamento
    While IE.Busy Or IE.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
        DoEvents
    Wend


    ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''Clica em "Pesquisar"

    Set htmlColl = IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("input")

    For Each Htmlinput In htmlColl

        If Trim(Htmlinput.Type) = "submit" Then
            Htmlinput.Click
            Do While IE.Busy Or IE.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
                DoEvents
            Loop
            Exit For
        End If
    Next Htmlinput


    ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

        ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''' Exibe 100 resultados

    Set htmlColl = IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("select")

    Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:02")
    For Each HTMLSelect In htmlColl

        Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")

        If Trim(HTMLSelect.Value) = "20" Or Trim(HTMLSelect.Value) = "50" Then
            HTMLSelect.Value = "100"
            HTMLSelect.onchange

            Exit For
        End If
    Next HTMLSelect
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''



''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''Pega o conteúdo da primeira página

    If Teste = "primeira" Then
        Z = 2
        Teste = "segunda"
    End If


    Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:02")
    With IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("tbody")(1)


        For Each tr In .Rows
        Dim newURL As String
        Dim newURL2 As String
        If tr.innerText <> "Nenhum resultado para esta consulta " Then
            newURL = Mid(tr.innerHTML, InStr(1, tr.innerHTML, ";") + 1, InStr(1, tr.innerHTML, "&amp;idContrato") - 1 - InStr(1, tr.innerHTML, ";"))
            newURL2 = Mid(tr.innerHTML, InStr(1, tr.innerHTML, "idContrato"), InStr(1, tr.innerHTML, "><u") - 2 - InStr(1, tr.innerHTML, ";idContrato"))
            newURL = "http://www3.transparencia.gov.br/TransparenciaPublica/jsp/contratos/contratoExtrato.jsf?consulta=3&" & newURL & "&" & newURL2
        End If
            For Each td In tr.Cells
                X = X + 1
                With Plan6.Range("a" & Z)
                    If X = 1 Then
                        Plan6.Cells(Z, X).Value = td.innerText
                    Else
                        If Left(td.innerText, 2) = " =" Then
                            Plan6.Cells(Z, X).Value = "..." & td.innerText
                        Else
                            Plan6.Cells(Z, X).Value = td.innerText
                        End If
                    End If
                End With
            Next td
        Plan6.Cells(Z, 7).Value = newURL
        Z = Z + 1
        X = 0
        Next tr
    End With

    If i = 0 Then
        i = 134     'Variável referente a páginas
    End If
    w = 136     'Variável referente ao orgão com mais de 10 paginas
    Do
        On Error Resume Next
        Teste = IE.Document.Links(135).innerText
        Teste2 = IE.Document.Links(134).innerText
        On Error GoTo 0
        If Teste2 = "[anterior]" Then
            If w = 146 Then         'Volta a contagem após clicar em [posterior]
                w = 136
            End If
            On Error GoTo Termina
            IE.Document.Links(w).Click
            On Error GoTo 0
            u = 1
            w = w + 1
            On Error GoTo 0

        ElseIf Teste = "[anterior]" Then
            If w = 146 Then         'Volta a contagem após clicar em [posterior]
                w = 135

            End If

        ElseIf Teste2 <> "[anterior]" And Teste = "[anterior]" Then     'Avança página
            IE.Document.Links(i).Click

        ElseIf Teste <> "[anterior]" And Teste2 = "[anterior]" And u <> 1 Then     'Avança página
                IE.Document.Links(i).Click
                u = 0

        ElseIf u <> i Then
            On Error GoTo Termina
                IE.Document.Links(i).Click
            On Error GoTo 0
                u = i

        Else
            IE.Document.Links(w).Click

        End If

        Do While IE.Busy Or IE.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
            DoEvents
        Loop

    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''Pega o conteúdo das demais páginas

    On Error GoTo Termina ''''''''''''Finaliza caso não tenha (mais) páginas.

    With IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("tbody")(1)

        For Each tr In .Rows
            newURL = "http://www3.transparencia.gov.br/TransparenciaPublica/jsp/contratos/contratoExtrato.jsf?consulta=3&" & Mid(tr.innerHTML, InStr(1, tr.innerHTML, ";") + 1, InStr(1, tr.innerHTML, "&amp;idContrato") - 1 - InStr(1, tr.innerHTML, ";")) & "&" & Mid(tr.innerHTML, InStr(1, tr.innerHTML, "idContrato"), InStr(1, tr.innerHTML, "><u") - 2 - InStr(1, tr.innerHTML, ";idContrato"))
                For Each td In tr.Cells
                    X = X + 1
                    With Plan6.Range("a" & Z)
                        If X = 1 Then
                        Plan6.Cells(Z, X).Value = td.innerText
                    Else
                        If Left(td.innerText, 2) = " =" Or Left(td.innerText, 1) = "=" Then
                            Plan6.Cells(Z, X).Value = "..." & td.innerText
                        Else
                            Plan6.Cells(Z, X).Value = td.innerText
                        End If
                    End If
                    End With
                Next td
            Plan6.Cells(Z, 7).Value = newURL
            Z = Z + 1
            X = 0
        Next tr
    i = i + 1
    End With
    Loop


''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''



Termina:
    IE.Quit
    If MacroLoop <> 0 Then
        MacroLoop = MacroLoop + 1
    End If
    i = 0
    Call TodosContratosOrgao5(MacroLoop, Z)
    Application.StatusBar = "Pronto."
    Exit Function

End Function



End Sub
```

Sorry for not posting de PasteHTML3 code, here it is. (It runs FINE, but it stops after some time!)

And I've got a button on my sheet that runs the macro before the ParseHTML:

```
Sub GetData()
    Dim Teste As String
    Plan6.UsedRange.ClearContents
    Range("D1").Calculate
    Range("E1").Calculate
    Range("C1").Calculate
    Teste = "primeira"
    Call ParseHTML3(Plan4.Range("C1").Value, 0, 0, Teste)

End Sub
```

Comment: What does `ParseHTML3` look like?

Comment: what is `ParseHTML3`?

Comment: Updated the main topic! Thanks for seeing this

Comment: do you have a `Workbook_SheetChange` or `Worksheet_Change` event in your spreadsheet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ErrorHandler (`Termina`) seems to be the case for the stack overflow:

You first call  (1) `ParseHTML3`. If something goes wrong, code execution will continue in `Termina` - calling (2) `TodosContratosOrgao5` with `MacroLoop+1`.

In `TodosContratosOrgao5` you then loop from MacroLoop to 589, calling (3) `ParseHTML3`. Assuming that the same error persists that happened in the first run, `ParseHTML3` will in fact call (4) `TodosContratosOrgao5` again, and so forth! Thus, you stack will continue to grow like this:

1. ParseHTML3
2. TodosContratosOrgao5
3. ParseHTML3
4. TodosContratosOrgao5
5. ...

What you probably want to do is to call `TodosContratosOrgao5` first (with the correct MacroLoop value) - and in case `ParseHTML3` causes an error, simply exit the function - and let `TodosContratosOrgao5` call the next line!

Also, try to find the bug in `ParseHTML3`, stepping through the code with <kbd>F8</kbd>!

Comment: PERFECT! I'm so dumb, I thought, for no reason, that the code was never going to go back to the previous sub if I didn't call it on the other function!

Answer (score 1):

Out of stack space means that you've got too many nested calls in your program. This is usually caused by circular referencing.

In this case, in `ParseHTML3` you call `TodosContratosOrgao5`, and in `TodosContratosOrgao5` you call `ParseHTML3`. This is never going to resolve out, but instead they'll keep calling each other again and again.

A simpler example of the issue would be:

```
Sub DoFoo()
     Call DoBar
End Sub

Sub DoBar()
    Call DoFoo
End Sub
```